# Trying to kill processes by name, but remains one..why?

Tags: bash, process, kill

I'm trying to kill all my mysqld process. But remains one, why?

```
javier@javier-mbp:~$ ps aux | grep mysqld
root       913  0.0  0.0   4220   704 ?        S    16:11   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/javier-mbp.pid
mysql     1408  0.1  2.0 609900 84480 ?        Sl   16:11   0:00 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/javier-mbp.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
javier    1995  0.0  0.0  13128  1056 pts/0    S+   16:12   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
javier@javier-mbp:~$ pkill mysqld
pkill: 913 - Operation not permitted
pkill: 1408 - Operation not permitted
javier@javier-mbp:~$ sudo pkill mysqld
[sudo] password for javier: 
javier@javier-mbp:~$ ps aux | grep mysqld
javier    2020  0.0  0.0  13124  1060 pts/0    S+   16:13   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
javier@javier-mbp:~$
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ps` command is showing the `grep mysqld` command to which you piped the `ps`.
No instance of mysqld is running.

Comment: Yes, and use killall instead of kill

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command to kill mysqld:

```
kill -9 `pgrep mysqld`
```

[man kill](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill) tells us that `KILL (9)` is used to force the signal to kill the application.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The process that the OP believes it's *remaining* is not mysql but the `grep mysql`.